# WIX Parent folder not getting removed during uninstallation though no files are left

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn, wix3.10

I have this MSI which is included in my burn bootstrap EXE. When I uninstall this MSI, and when there are no other MSIs left installed, uninstalling this MSI wouldn't remove the parent installation folder (testInstallDir). Below is my wix file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="MosquittoInstaller" Language="1033" Version="3.0.7.0" Manufacturer="Zone24x7" UpgradeCode="b2cb73e9-bce8-463f-986d-b3f8f13283dd">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Platform="x64"/>

    <MajorUpgrade   DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"/>

    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MosquittoInstaller" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="MosquittoFilesGroup"/>
        </Feature>
    </Product>

  <Fragment>

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION">
        <Directory Id="testInstallDir" Name="test2.0">
          <Directory Id="MyProgramDir" Name="Mosquitto" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <CustomAction Id='RunMosquitto'  FileKey="fil7D28AEF774656849395A2FA20A5C963D"  Execute="deferred" ExeCommand='-v' Return="asyncNoWait" HideTarget="no" Impersonate="no"/>
    </Fragment>


  <Fragment>

    <DirectoryRef Id="MyProgramDir">
      <Directory Id="dirC8FCCB6AC509A125EE3B37CC7E907774" Name="devel" />
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="MosquittoFilesGroup">
      <Component Id="cmp4D47D22EE0C10F2FE658B4D343E1153F" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="5458BA33-9B08-46E1-8EE7-DE516F2FEF64">
        <File Id="filFC4C205CAB822D245B62422765716A32" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/aclfile.example" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp3245A363F29E5F92EEFB67D8F4A466FD" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="1ED7F2BD-692C-4C96-8CF5-C2064B64BF8D">
        <File Id="filB660EA30BBEBA21E457F2F3CA4811CC9" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/ChangeLog.txt" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmpA2A091D2A61C720ED9AE76DAF2674BE6" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="5F780D6F-F8BB-4BF6-84F6-EF8613404775">
        <File Id="fil83340F4F2CEADCD75C02CB23AEE43E5B" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/edl-v10" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp6F9F08890072C152F5FADAD0D513493C" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="BE80EDA6-28FC-4C0D-8BAC-94FA8AE5BB94">
        <File Id="fil60C98E7B75120C739F33F0C7ABF52318" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/epl-v10" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmpB04A2DC39867DD744B3591AC2AFB49BC" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="236F6263-DCDB-42BC-8DA3-8D23189EC331">
        <File Id="fil93F56A00DDA348881B22245DADDB4F5A" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/libeay32.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp3FA55FD836AD7B4095DAFD837A100110" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="7ED4C914-E66F-4F39-AC4E-A24123BF394C">
        <File Id="fil711449631134E31C4C38DCA6C4FCD922" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/libssl32.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmpBA00B50D8224C040011EC424B900FE43" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="EF6C19F7-CCC3-4C61-B5B8-DE01A0C6D55E">
        <File Id="filA995207A6EF3FF0B4A1912B4627C6A9E" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp4587500C7F4126281D74E67979861A5F" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="E81C33BB-226C-40F2-AE05-6F0EDFEDEA00">
        <File Id="filF89C2DB7028E205E7170A35A8F9520E6" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/mosquitto.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp59455E1C37B7879C4BC250DE3D60A2AD" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="179B4F4C-912B-4CA1-8F08-5E1B4ADFFD8B">
        <File Id="fil7D28AEF774656849395A2FA20A5C963D" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/mosquitto.exe" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmpFC2AA06F4719D34513B7E5E9EB230B41" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="C9CD68F9-77B1-481B-91ED-21AC8A84C4D7">
        <File Id="fil217773E50C3CCD997EE125E6B0195649" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/mosquittopp.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp783743C36FE8E1154B0AE9E72AC7D575" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="B5717FA1-FE2D-4617-814E-4492EA4D8807">
        <File Id="filCB4D3062E6881D66561E91BD301B39EC" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/mosquitto_passwd.exe" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmpB524C33DDFC8EBC62B98F9EBFC7807D0" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="68E7A8B3-DC15-404F-98D1-20487419D254">
        <File Id="fil5F8821D626DC542D506A561E82B226A6" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/mosquitto_pub.exe" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp3F0A99A6FCDA4B694FD5CFAFDC8A80CF" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="7B83878B-3F39-4FFA-8FDC-FDFA88E882A5">
        <File Id="fil4C12390E7E7C75828D70CEBED7733FCE" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/mosquitto_sub.exe" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmpEA7CE0C91970F57073BB84F8319AB6E9" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="34F20F13-0533-4029-87BE-C248FEBC8BC6">
        <File Id="fil431A1BF1C3B5AC45CE630487A7C4F945" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/pthreadVC2.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp7501765F72B0586A968FAC0B19C630D3" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="4A041354-E31D-4074-83EA-5EB162E9088F">
        <File Id="fil542FD8A849709E85C839FE825E8F7381" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/pwfile.example" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp9AA04B6F826A4FBEDDADF82E79A761E1" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="B48E76CB-C1A4-4E33-8D1C-93F17CF02CEE">
        <File Id="fil9A73011E316138ECF5FA538F5FFA4E65" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/readme-windows.txt" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp32A4C8B2CEA9C2B249897CE3C6B247C6" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="584E5D69-990B-4CA7-808E-B0CB16061501">
        <File Id="fil5ED5D6BCA1089DC259C7CBA92488771F" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/readme.txt" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmpC98F4A8F1680E1A63542439212B11AE5" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="6B20C0FB-1EF6-47FA-8CF7-6670388E1EE4">
        <File Id="fil85C65E95EE6846B0F10A532F68143610" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/ssleay32.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp077EB2DAE856A91792B2F5D25E1657B1" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="380D7E34-F52D-495B-AD44-98496DA86C39">
        <File Id="fil2C766C617C17E139FD0C4383EA2836C2" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/Uninstall.exe" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp75F7F5A733463114C1AE70CEE007EF5B" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="87C8326B-F7BE-48F4-B8E6-3C328EE3699B">
        <File Id="fil6EFD0D9154A77F9F83AD40E108ABC645" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/websockets.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmpED679856D0F7640ABA659DEB9A01EB0C" Directory="dirC8FCCB6AC509A125EE3B37CC7E907774" Guid="B576C2B4-4157-469C-86E2-B869214CC64A">
        <File Id="fil2AC1DBC8C2D9F23E430E4C762DCDE74D" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/devel/mosquitto.h" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp6E8EC27B07C11656CE96CA872FF39F60" Directory="dirC8FCCB6AC509A125EE3B37CC7E907774" Guid="78387CDF-FE90-464A-8D3F-BDD42B89C26C">
        <File Id="filEEC89BDE9E29C6E182307F4C6826890A" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/devel/mosquitto.lib" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp85BF1685089A4DC262B71CEDC73FA6B3" Directory="dirC8FCCB6AC509A125EE3B37CC7E907774" Guid="F434B6D5-8A93-43CF-AC26-DE89F52E5A7E">
        <File Id="fil7F5D72039158A30AF8EAA068868BBEF6" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/devel/mosquittopp.h" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp8D747BA62B3F712D6A73536CB1C1EA26" Directory="dirC8FCCB6AC509A125EE3B37CC7E907774" Guid="BBF1DD11-F7C9-4823-ADC4-B31657B05ECF">
        <File Id="filA474F6FBE224F895B1554D05DE2F419D" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/devel/mosquittopp.lib" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmpB2DF497560B4E99936D5598EE54D381B" Directory="dirC8FCCB6AC509A125EE3B37CC7E907774" Guid="B0A4C898-AC74-4329-A88E-9321381B0EB9">
        <File Id="fil0F36E85111041DA1F5ABEFF409812AFA" KeyPath="yes" Source="../../../Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto/devel/mosquitto_plugin.h" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

What am I doing wrong here? There are no files left. Just the empty test2.0 folder remains. Please advice.

Comment: Are you running any files as a service such as mosquitto.exe? There could be locks on the folder in question if a service was not stopped properly before the uninstall proceeds. You don't need custom actions to start and stop services, the functionality is built into MSI. Just use the proper tables / elements to implement it to start on install and stop on uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally msiexec /x {ProductGUID} should remove all folders and files unless components are marked shared/permanent, if not it's an issue with your setup or something you're doing with your application. Please provide other details related to this.
As a last resort you can use REMOVEFILE to remove the directory during Uninstallation:

`<Component Id="NEWCOMP" Guid="">
          <RemoveFile Id="RemoveInstallFolder" Name="*" On="uninstall" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
</Component>`